# Unable to locate package ros-indigo-roscpp

Tags: ros, tum-simulator, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on ubuntu 16.04, trying to install tum_simulator using the tutorial here: https://github.com/dougvk/tum_simulator

I first got stuck here:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

but used the solution found here: [Can't resolve package dependencies when building ros for Ubuntu 16.04](http://answers.ros.org/question/232795) by typing `--os=ubuntu:trusty` with the `rosdep` command.

however with this command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --os=ubuntu:trusty
```

I get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-roscpp
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-roscpp] failed
```

I can't find how to install the package `roscpp` manually or how to continue the installation.

Thanks for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246292/unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-roscpp/) by [frenchie007](https://answers.ros.org/users/28325/frenchie007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-10-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-24**:
The `README.md` in the repository you linked also explicitly state that those instructions are for Indigo:

> tum_simulator on Indigo

To use them on Kinetic, you'll have to adapt them as you follow along.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-24**:
You might run into some problems with Gazebo versions > 2.2 and the `tum_*` packages on Kinetic, even if you get the `rosdep` step to finish successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am on ubuntu 16.04 [..]

and:

> however with this command:

> ```
> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y --os=ubuntu:trusty
> ```

> I get this error

> ```
> E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-roscpp
> ```

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y ros-indigo-roscpp] failed
```

Indigo is not supported / released on Ubuntu Xenial (16.04), which means that `ros-indigo-roscpp` doesn't exist there. Forcing `rosdep` to use the `ubuntu:trusty` defintions isn't going to change that.

You could try and see whether

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src
```

*after* having `source`d the correct (Kinetic) `setup.bash` works.

PS: this is exactly why I never really use `--rosdistro $DISTRO` in command line examples: the instructions will get copy/pasted by someone in the future on a different OS/ROS release and no longer work. `--rosdistro $DISTRO` is only needed if you don't have a `setup.bash` sourced anyway.

---

Edit:

> I'm not sure what you mean by sourcing the correct setup.bash..

That would be `source /opt/ros/$DISTRO/setup.bash`. That will set the relevant environment variables, making `--rosdistro ..` unnecessary.

> I decided to try to follow the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator#Installation
> but to no avail, probably because I also have a different os version

Yes, those instructions are even older than the ones you found on `dougvk/tum_simulator`. Especially `rosmake` and friends are deprecated.

> Is there a newer version of `tum_simulator`?

Not that I know of, but I'm really not into UAVs / quadrotors. You should probably spend some time searching for some, and / or try to contact a community. See [Any quadrotor simulation package in ROS Kinetic?](http://answers.ros.org/question/246085) for a similar question.

But to get back to your original problem: can you show us the commands you've used and what their output was?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [frenchie007](https://answers.ros.org/users/28325/frenchie007/) on 2016-10-24**:
I'm not sure what you mean by sourcing the correct setup.bash..

I decided to try to follow the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/tum_simulator#Installation
but to no avail, probably because I also have a different os version

Is there a newer version of tum_simulator?

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
@frenchie007 AFAIK, the newest version is only Indigo.The indigo version itself is still not official ( not merged to the main repo).

I use the indigo version from dougvk github. It works fine! Just that the demo is not as complete as the official one,  But that's not a problem for me

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-25**:
@alienmon: does it also work on ROS Kinetic? Because that is what the OP seems to be having problems with.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
That one I'm not so sure, cause I only tried with indigo. I don't think it will work,  Buy maybe you can just try out @frenchie007

**Comment by [frenchie007](https://answers.ros.org/users/28325/frenchie007/) on 2016-10-25**:
okay actually the simulator opens up but I can't control the drone.. I think it might be similar to here
http://answers.ros.org/question/221691/not-working-command-line-control-in-tum_simulator/
I think I will just use a vm to have ubuntu precise and use the old instructions. thanks for you help

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-25**:\

> I think I will just use a vm to have ubuntu precise and use the old instructions.

I would, if you can, use at least the Indigo version, which according to @alienmon, should work under Trusty.

**Comment by [alienmon](https://answers.ros.org/users/27685/alienmon/) on 2016-10-25**:
I use Ubuntu 14.04 , and ROS indigo